# Android: How to make background angular

Tags: android, background

I want to have my background angular like you can see in this picture:

[image]

How can I manage this?

Comment: I would use a 9-patch bitmap: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use background-image for example

Comment: What about the size of the image? I want that it looks exactly the same on every screen size.

Comment: so you want fixed angle no matter screen size?

Comment: it will strectch to it, I don't know what you exactly want :)